# Alternative to gnome-terminal command in Windows

Tags: gnome

In our internal tool, there a command to start [WildFly Server](https://www.wildfly.org/) . But this will work only with Linux

```
gnome-terminal --window --maximize -- /bin/sh -c $var_wildflyHome/bin/standalone.sh &
```

Is there any solution to make this work at windows OS ?